# How to split body from a post request

Tags: python, encoding, split, python-requests

I am trying to split the body from a post request, and i am wondering what is the best way to do it. I was thinking on splitting by "&" to extract each parameter, and then by "=" to extract the pair field/value

```
data1=value&data2=value2
```

It will split as follows:

```
data1 value
data2 value2
```

However, if the data received contains an "&" or an "=", it will not work: the `split` method interprets that character in the value as a separator, removing it and creating another field.  The best example here is a value received in base64. For example, "value" is represented in base64 as dmFsdWU=

```
data1=dmFsdWU=&data2=value2
```

It will split as:

```
data1 dmFsdWU 
data2 value2
```

Any suggestion on what could i do here? I was thinking on encode the value of the data, so dmFsdWU= is received as dmFsdWU%3D, but i dont know if there is a better solution

Thanks

Comment: why not use a standard library to do this? something like `urlparse.parse_qs`

Answer (score 2):

Use the second parameter of `split` to limit the splitting:

```
in_str = "data1=dmFsdWU=&data2=value2"
param_list = [param_expr.split('=', 1) for param_expr in in_str.split('&')]
```

Result:

```
[['data1', 'dmFsdWU='], ['data2', 'value2']]
```

*Deficiency*

You haven't described your full interpretation grammar: what to do if the first value contains a `&`.  For instance, change your example to

data1=dmFsd&WU&data2=value2

Where you intend

```
data1 dmFsd&WU
data2 value2
```

What parsing rules obtain here?  Are there restrictions on the field name that will disambiguate this?  For instance, if the field name must be alphanumeric, then your parsing job is possible, but becomes a little trickier:

- Find the first `=`; this determines the first field name
- Find the next `&` ...
- Find the next `=`; this is the end of the second field name
- Locate the alphanumeric sequence ending at that latter `=`; use this as the second field name.

  You have now determined the two field names; the remaining two strings are the values.

---

**HOWEVER**

Note that there are pathological strings the cannot be parsed uniquely into a pair of field/value pairs.  Most simply, let's take your given example:

```
data1=value&data2=value2
```

Why is this not a single field/value pair?

```
data1 value&data2=value2
```

You will run into this any time a value is allowed to contain both `&` and `=`.

Comment: It solves the issue with the = character, but what if there is an &, as for example

user=jack&jones&password=1234

It parses it as [['user', 'jack'], ['jones'], ['password', '1234']]

Comment: @JaviDR: that's another good point past the ones I raised.  I think we're in the realm of turning the problem back to OP for a good coding attempt -- we're about to become a coding service.

Comment: @JaviDR -- I walked through my examples again; the final algorithm I laid out -- posted about the same time as your comment -- works on the case you give.  It finds `user`, then `password`.

Comment: Hi. No, that code returns [['user', 'jack'], ['jones'], ['password', '1234']], when i expected it to return [['user', 'jack&jones'], ['password', '1234']]

Comment: @JaviDR: the last algorithm, not the code that I posted.